# service cannot acquire lock on AWS but it work fine in local machine

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, locking

```
 lock(name: string, expirationTime: number) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.redisClient
                .setnx(name, 'locked')
                .then(async (res) => {
                    if (res == 1) {
                        await this.redisClient.expire(name, expirationTime)
                        resolve('OK')
                    } else reject('Lock already held by another client')
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    reject(err)
                })
        })
    }

    releaseLock(name: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.redisClient
                .del(name)
                .then((res) => {
                    resolve('OK')
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    reject(err)
                })
        })
    }
```

I have used the above codes to acquire lock and release it and it works fine in local pc but it does not work on AWS. event ot does not raise any error

usage:

```
   this.redisDataServices
            .lock('publisher:lock', 30)
            .then(async (lock) => {
                  // do something...
            })
```